# C#のListView（details）でダブルバッファすると真っ黒になる

Tags: c#

C#でpagePanel（Panel コントロール）上に配置したListViewがサイズ変更時やリストアイテム更新時にちらつくため、以下のコードにてちらつきを抑えています。
しかし、この方法ではListViewのLargeIcon、SmallIcon、Listでは問題なくダブルバッファが働きますがDetails状態の時、ListViewが真っ黒になってしまいます。対処方法をご存じでしたらお教えください。
なお、ListViewを継承した独自クラスを作成し、DoubleBuffered = trueとする方法ではちらつきは解消されませんので、他の解決方法を知りたいです。

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern UInt32 GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern UInt32 SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int index, UInt32 unValue);

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;

    public void PagePanelDoubleBufferOn()
    {
        UInt32 exStyle = GetWindowLong(pagePanel.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(pagePanel.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_COMPOSITED);
    }

    public void PagePanelDoubleBufferOff()
    {
        UInt32 exStyle = GetWindowLong(pagePanel.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(pagePanel.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle & ~WS_EX_COMPOSITED);
    }
```

Comment: 貴方が関連していると考えた情報だけで無く、他の人が推測や試行錯誤無しに問題を再現できる程度のソースコードや情報をすべて提示した方が良いでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Detailsビューの場合、ListViewコントロールは単一のウィンドウではなく、ヘッダーコントロールなどの複数のウィンドウを組み合わせる構成となりますのでうまくいかないのかもしれません。そもそもとして、WS_EX_COMPOSITEDは奥の手であって、多用は避けるべきものという認識です。[DOBON.NETさんでもリスクについて言及されています。](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/control/doublebuffered.html#wsexcomposited)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。DOBON.NETさんのページを参照してWS_EX_COMPOSITEDを使っております。やはりDetails表示の場合にはWS_EX_COMPOSITEDを使用しない、Details以外では使用するといった条件分けで対応するしかないのですかね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ダブルバッファを使うようにしてみました。
カラムがパラパラ表示されることはなくなりますが、少し重たい印象をうけるかもしれません。

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_PAINT:
                WmPaint(ref m);
                break;

            case WM_ERASEBKGND:
                // 無視
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void WmPaint(ref Message m) {
        if (m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero) {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps = new PAINTSTRUCT();
            IntPtr dc = BeginPaint(m.HWnd, ref ps);
            try {
                var context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
                using (var bufferedGraphics = context.Allocate(dc, ClientRectangle)) {
                    var clip = Rectangle.FromLTRB(ps.rcPaint.Left, ps.rcPaint.Top,
                                                 ps.rcPaint.Right, ps.rcPaint.Bottom);
                    bufferedGraphics.Graphics.SetClip(clip);
                    DrawNative(bufferedGraphics.Graphics, clip);
                    bufferedGraphics.Render();
                }
            } finally {
                EndPaint(m.HWnd, ref ps);
            }
        } else {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHdc(m.WParam)) {
                DrawNative(g, ClientRectangle);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DrawNative(Graphics g, Rectangle clip) {
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor)) {
            g.FillRectangle(brush, clip);
        }
        IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
        try {
            IntPtr flags = (IntPtr)(PRF_CHILDREN | PRF_CLIENT | PRF_ERASEBKGND);
            Message msg = Message.Create(Handle, WM_PRINT, hdc, flags);
            base.DefWndProc(ref msg);
        } finally {
            g.ReleaseHdc();
        }
    }

    private const int
        WM_PAINT            = 0x000F,
        WM_ERASEBKGND       = 0x0014,
        WM_PRINT            = 0x0317;

    private const int
        PRF_CHECKVISIBLE    = 0x00000001,
        PRF_NONCLIENT       = 0x00000002,
        PRF_CLIENT          = 0x00000004,
        PRF_ERASEBKGND      = 0x00000008,
        PRF_CHILDREN        = 0x00000010;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PAINTSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr hdc;
        public bool fErase;
        public RECT rcPaint;
        public bool fRestore;
        public bool fIncUpdate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public byte[] rgbReserved;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr BeginPaint(IntPtr hWnd, ref PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EndPaint(IntPtr hWnd, ref PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);
}
```

【解説】

コントロールの描画は WM_PAINT メッセージに応答することで行われています。

「WM_PAINT メッセージの使用」
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/gdi/using-the-wm-paint-message

「クライアント領域での描画」
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-in-the-client-area

通常は BeginPaint API で得られた HDC (デバイスコンテキストハンドル) に対して描画処理を行うのですが、描画するものが多くなるとちらつきが発生します。
そこで、いったんバッファにそれらを書き込み、完了したら HDC に一挙に転送するのがダブルバッファ処理です。

BufferedGraphicsManager で BufferedGraphics(バッファ)を確保し、書き込みを行った後、Render メソッドで一挙に転送しています。

バッファへの書き込みには WM_PRINT メッセージを使用しています。

「WM_PRINT メッセージ」
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/gdi/wm-print

Control.DrawToBitmap で呼ばれているメッセージです。
wParam に HDC, lParam にどの部分を描画するかをセットしてメッセージを送ると HDC に描画してくれます。

この方法は、DrawToBitmap が正常に動作するコントロールならどれでも使えます。
Windows Forms のコントロールの中では RichTextBox, WebBrowser が使えないようです。

TexBox 等、多くのコントロールは WM_PAINT の wPram に HDC をセットすると描画してくれるのですが、ListView はそうなっていなかったようです。

このしくみを使うと、Bitmap に描画させ、それを加工して描画することもできます。

TextBox にプレースホルダを表示したり、DateTimePicker の文字色や背景色を変更することも可能です。

「WM_PAINTでTextBoxがちらつく」
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/d5ac1426-1082-43a1-a02f-677dad1ee3ca/wmpaint12391textbox1236412385124251238812367?forum=csharpgeneralja

「DateTimePickerの文字色を変更したい」
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/80860829-22a7-4647-999e-ad594ccff48b/datetimepicker12398259912338333394124342279326356123751238312356?forum=csharpgeneralja

Comment: KOZ様。ご回答ありがとうございます。さっそく使用させていただきましたが、いただいた回答がまさにほしいものでした。全くちらつきがなく、ListViewをdetailsにしても画面が黒くなることなく、きびきび動作しました。今まで試行錯誤したのは何だったのか、感動すら覚えました。いただいたコードの内容は私には少し高度な内容なので、勉強したいと思います。ここで質問してよかったです。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご希望に添えて何よりです。ちょっと解説もしておきました。

Comment: KOZ様。解説までいただきありがとうございます。勉強になります。ListView以外にも使えるとのことで、Panelにも応用させていただきました。なお、ListViewExを使用してみての報告になりますが、アイテムをクリックして名前変更する時に残像が残りました（名前を短くしていくと編集BOXの右側に線が残る。名前変更を完了すると消える）。DrawNative内のPRF_CHILDRENを削除したら残像は出なくなり完璧に動作しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: > DrawNative内のPRF_CHILDRENを削除したら残像は出なくなり完璧に動作しました。
こういうこともあるんですね。ありがとうございました。
Panel はもともと UserPaint されているので DoubleBuffered = true で事足りるはずです。

Comment: PanelはDoubleBuffered = trueだけでもちらつきなく動作しました。アドバイスありがとうございました。